# Largest rectangle not touching any rock in a square field

Tags: cg.comp-geom

Following [this mathematical question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1534120/largest-rectangle-not-touching-any-rock-in-a-square-field), I am interested in the algorithmic question:

> Given $n$ points in the unit square, 
>   find the largest area of an axis-parallel rectangle in the unit square
>   that does not contain any of the given points in its interior.

What is known about this problem?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what are some applications of this problem?

Comment: @Mehrdad it is related to my research about fair division of land. I started from the following variation on the fair-cake-cutting problem: --- "A father has a square land-plot and $n$ children. Each child has a different value-measure regarding the land-plot. The father wants to give each child a land-plot with a positive measure. Then, he wants to leave for himself a rectangular land-plot as large as possible." --- Apparently, the worst case is that each child wants a very specific location (a point). Then, the problem reduces to what I asked above.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[There is an $O(n \log^2 n)$ time algorithm](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=41988). [Aggarwal and Suri 87]

It seems to be the state of the art.

Comment: Thanks! After learning that the name of the problem is "largest empty rectangle", I found many other related references: http://www.citeulike.org/user/erelsegal-halevi/tag/largest-rectangle